# How to set "interact with desktop" in windows service installer

Tags: c#, service

I have a windows service which runs under system account and executes some programs from time to time (*yeah,yeah, I know that's a bad practice, but that's not my decision*). I need to set the "interact with desktop" check, to see the gui of that executed programs, after the service is installed. I've tried several ways, putting the code below in AfterInstall or OnCommited event handlers of my service installer:

```
ConnectionOptions coOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
coOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope mgmtScope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"root\CIMV2", coOptions);
mgmtScope.Connect();

ManagementObject wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + ServiceMonitorInstaller.ServiceName + "'");

ManagementBaseObject InParam = wmiService.GetMethodParameters("Change");
InParam["DesktopInteract"] = true;
ManagementBaseObject OutParam = wmiService.InvokeMethod("Change", InParam, null);
```

or

```
 RegistryKey ckey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WindowsService1", true);

  if(ckey != null)
  {
    if(ckey.GetValue("Type") != null)
    {
      ckey.SetValue("Type", ((int)ckey.GetValue("Type") | 256));
    }
  }
```

both of these methods "work". They set the check, but after I start the service it launches the exe - and gui isn't shown! So, if I stop the service, recheck and start it again - bingo! everything starts and is shown. The second way to achieve the result is to reboot - after it the gui is also shown.

So the question is: Is there a correct way to set "interact with desktop" check, so it'll start working without rechecks and reboots?

OS: Windows XP (haven't tried Vista and 7 yet...)

Comment: tried to use "sc config" command - no way...

Comment: tried to use winapi exports from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/WindowsServiceInstall.aspx - without luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And finally after searching the internet for a week - I've found a great working solution:
http://asprosys.blogspot.com/2009/03/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop.html

> Find the desktop to launch into. This
>   may seem facetious but it isn't as
>   simple as it seems. With Terminal
>   Services and Fast User Switching there
>   can be multiple interactive users
>   logged on to the computer at the same
>   time. If you want the user that is
>   currently sitting at the physical
>   console then you're in luck, the
>   Terminal Services API call
>   WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId will get
>   you the session ID you need. If your
>   needs are more complex (i.e. you need
>   to interact with a specific user on a
>   TS server or you need the name of the
>   window station in a non-interactive
>   session) you'll need to enumerate the
>   Terminal Server sessions with
>   WTSEnumerateSessions and check the
>   session for the information you need
>   with WTSGetSessionInformation.
>
> Now you know what session you need to
>   interact with and you have its ID.
>   This is the key to the whole process,
>   using WTSQueryUserToken and the
>   session ID you can now retrieve the
>   token of the user logged on to the
>   target session. This completely
>   mitigates the security problem of the
>   'interact with the desktop' setting,
>   the launched process will not be
>   running with the LOCAL SYSTEM
>   credentials but with the same
>   credentials as the user that is
>   already logged on to that session! No
>   privilege elevation.
>
> Using CreateProcessAsUser and the
>   token we have retrieved we can launch
>   the process in the normal way and it
>   will run in the target session with
>   the target user's credentials. There
>   are a couple of caveats, both
>   lpCurrentDirectory and lpEnvironment
>   must point to valid values - the
>   normal default resolution methods for
>   these parameters don't work for
>   cross-session launching. You can use
>   CreateEnvironmentBlock to create a
>   default environment block for the
>   target user.

There is source code of the working project attached.

Comment: This Code is great but does anyone know how to specify arguments when launching the application?

Answer (score 6):

```
private static void SetInterActWithDeskTop()
        {
            var service = new System.Management.ManagementObject(
                    String.Format("WIN32_Service.Name='{0}'", "YourServiceName"));
            try
            {
                var paramList = new object[11];
                paramList[5] = true;
                service.InvokeMethod("Change", paramList);
            }
            finally
            {
                service.Dispose();
            }


        }
```

Comment: works good. You can check it manually that the flag is set correctly

Answer (score 2):

Same as Heisa but with WMI. (code is Powershell, but can be easily ported to C#)

```
if ($svc = gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -eq $svcname})
{
    try {
        $null = $svc.change($svc.displayname,$svc.pathname,16,1,`
        "Manual",$false,$svc.startname,$null,$null,$null,$null)
        write-host "Change made"
    catch { throw "Error: $_" }
} else
{ throw "Service $svcname not installed" }
```

See [MSDN: Service Change() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for param description.

Comment: Small improvement:
`$svc = gwmi win32_service -Filter "name='$svcname'"`
will filter more efficiently.
Also, the change will only be visible after the service is restarted.